# How to set a window property through the Windows API (VARIANT_TRUE)?

Tags: c#, windows-8, desktop-application, gesture, windows-api-code-pack

I'm working on Windows 8 and I want to try to disable the default edge gesture behaviors when my desktop app is fullscreen.

I've found this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which explains how to do it in C++.

My app is a WPF/C# application and I've found the [Windows Code API Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) and the [SetWindowProperty](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=59) method to to the job.

**Problem**

I don't know how to pass the right parameter, which is a boolean :

> PropertyKey key = new
>   PropertyKey("32CE38B2-2C9A-41B1-9BC5-B3784394AA44", 2);
>   WindowProperties.SetWindowProperty(this, key, "true");
>
> PropertyKey key = new
>   PropertyKey("32CE38B2-2C9A-41B1-9BC5-B3784394AA44", 2);
>   WindowProperties.SetWindowProperty(this, key, "-1");
>
> PropertyKey key = new
>   PropertyKey("32CE38B2-2C9A-41B1-9BC5-B3784394AA44", 2);
>   WindowProperties.SetWindowProperty(this, key, "VARIANT_TRUE");

As you can see, the parameter has to be a string but no one works.

If someone has an idea, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution would be using [Windows API Code Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/).

The code setting **System.AppUserModel.PreventPinning** property would be as easy as:

```
public static void PreventPinning(Window window)
{
    var preventPinningProperty = new PropertyKey(new Guid("9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3"), 9);
    WindowProperties.SetWindowProperty(window, preventPinningProperty, "1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the original signature, the function needs an `IntPtr` handle, a `Guid` id and an `PropertyStore` object that will be populated by the data.

```
HRESULT SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(
  _In_   HWND hwnd,
  _In_   REFIID riid,
  _Out_  void **ppv
);
```

Translating this into c# would look like this:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern int SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(
        IntPtr handle,
        ref Guid riid,
        out IPropertyStore propertyStore);
```

And you can grab the `IPropertyStore` interface from [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IPropertyStore.html):

```
[ComImport, Guid("886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IPropertyStore
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetCount([Out] out uint cProps);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetAt([In] uint iProp, out PropertyKey pkey);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void GetValue([In] ref PropertyKey key, out object pv);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void SetValue([In] ref PropertyKey key, [In] ref object pv);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void Commit();
    }
```

The only thing left is to actually implement the `PropertyStore`. Similar implementations in the .net framework can be found in e.g. [PrintSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printsystemobject.aspx).

After implementing this you should be able to simply call the method and set the property:

```
IPropertyStore store = new PropertyStore(); 

//your propery id in guid
var g = new Guid("32CE38B2-2C9A-41B1-9BC5-B3784394AA44");
SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(this.Handle, ref g, out store);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've implemented the PropertyStore (thanks to a Dictionary). I've used your last three lines in my MainWindow.xaml.cs (so this.Handle became new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle). But the store returned by SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow is null whereas my three parameters aren't... Any idea ?

Comment: You can start by capturing the return value of the function and comparing that to common results:

`int result =  SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(this.Handle, ref g, out store);`

And compare that to common [HRESULTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The result is -2147024809, "Invalid argument". My handle is always 0, maybe it comes from it.

Comment: Ah right, the example code is still for old winforms. For wpf you need: `IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;`

Comment: Yeah I've already tried it. I've moved my code in the "Loaded" event of my window and I haven't this error anymore. But I have a new one, "No such interface supported" :)

Comment: Ah, this seems a problem with the implementation of the Interface (which is a different problem:)). Check this Q&A on ["C# wrapper interface error: E_NOINTERFACE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935768/c-sharp-wrapper-interface-error-e-nointerface)

Comment: @Max, can you provide any direction on your implementation of the PropertyStore class.  Not sure where to go with this one.

Comment: The `IPropertyStore store = new PropertyStore();` is unnecessary because the variable is overwritten by the out-parameter anyways, as such implementing the interface yourself is unnecessary as well. -- the whole point of the API is to get access to the Windows property store, not writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to pass the right parameter, which is a boolean. As you can see, the parameter has to be a string but no one works.

Pass the string `"1"` for `true`, or `"0"` for `false`.