# : 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, interop

I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063034-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'

The code from which the error arises:

```
foreach (MailItem item in mailItems)
{
}
```

Comment: Your mailItems does not contain MailItem object, does it ?

Comment: @FlorianMichel the `foreach` loop runs for while and the gives the error.

Comment: Regarding your error message, I suggest you to check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935768/c-sharp-wrapper-interface-error-e-nointerface

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that `mailItems` contains more objects other than `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem` as defined in the loop. The safest way is using `object` type to iterate `mailItems`, then check its type with `as` operator before running Outlook handler:

```
foreach (object item in mailItems)
{
    // try casting to Outlook.MailItem first
    var obj = item as Outlook.MailItem;

    // check if the conversion works and UnRead property can be accessed as well
    if (obj != null && obj.UnRead == true)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: did that, but i get the following error - `'object' does not contain a definition for 'UnRead' and no extension method 'UnRead' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found`

Comment: `UnRead` property exists in `Outlook.MailItem`, I changed to use `as` operator for type conversion attempt.